# Editing data with jQuery in modal won't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on something to store matches/events in a database. I like to note that this is my first use of jQuery. Everything is pretty much done, expect this problem.

I use PHP to create a list of teams. When a 'team' is selected, the matches of that team are loaded into div "display". Every match has a id, title, date and time field.

```
<?php
// show_overview.php
$event_info = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT e.match_id, e.title, e.date, e.starttime
                                    FROM matches AS e
                                    WHERE e.team_id = '$team' AND e.date >= CURDATE()
                                    ORDER BY e.date asc;");

foreach($event_info as $row) {
    $events[] = array('match_id' => $row['match_id'], 'title' => stripslashes($row['title']), 'date' => $row['date'], 'starttime' => $row['starttime']);
}

$data['events'] = $events;  

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Here we have the body of the page. In the dropdown box you can select your team.

```
                <!-- BEGIN MATCHES -->
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="team-matchlist" class="col-sm-8 col-md-7 col-form-label">Kies van welk team je de wedstrijden wilt zien:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3 mb-5">
                            <select class="form-control" id="team-matchlist" name="team-matchlist">
                                <?php
                                // Create a list of teams to select the matches. This is loaded in the header. The list is correctly showing.
                                // $teams = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY team;");
                                if ($hierarchy_session >= 3):
                                    while($team = mysqli_fetch_assoc($teams)):
                                        echo '<option value="' . $team['team_id'] . '">' . $team['team'] . '</option>';
                                    endwhile;
                                    mysqli_data_seek($teams, 0);
                                else:
                                    echo '<option value="' . $team_id_session . '">' . $teamname_session . '</option>';
                                endif;
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Here is the match data loaded -->
                        <div id="display" class="container"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- END MATCHES -->
```

In  are the matches loaded. There are two buttons created for editing a match. It won't connect the data to the modal. I can't get my head around it. I think it's a binding problem, but I can't make it to work.

If I use php directly to export the data, it works. But when I load the data in jQuery. It won't load the data in the body of the modal.

I looked at [bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/), but I couldn't make that work. I hope someone can make me look in the right direction. I tried to make the code as little as possible.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // BEGIN SHOW MATCHES
            // Create a list of all the matches from database
            // When a team is selected
            $("#team-matchlist").change(function () {
                var team = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "show_overview.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        team: team
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        var i;

                        var display = document.getElementById("display");
                        if (response.events.length > 0) {
                            display.innerHTML =  "";

                            var user_hierarchy = '<?php echo $hierarchy_session;?>';
                            var user_team = '<?php echo $team_id_session;?>';

                            for (i = 0; i<response.events.length; i++) {
                                display.innerHTML += (
                                    "<form method='post' class='mb-5 text-md-right'>" +
                                    "<div class='form-group row'>" +
                                    "<label for='firstname' class='col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-form-label'>Titel</label>" +
                                    "<div class='col-sm-8 col-md-9'>" +
                                    "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='etitle-" + response.events[i].match_id + "' name='title' value='" + response.events[i].title + "'>" +
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "<div class='form-group row'>" +
                                    "<label for='lastname' class='col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-form-label'>Datum</label>" +
                                    "<div class='col-sm-8 col-md-9'>" +
                                    "<input type='date' class='form-control' id='edate-" + response.events[i].match_id + "' name='date' value='" + response.events[i].date + "'>" +
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "<div class='form-group row'>" +
                                    "<label for='lastname' class='col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-form-label'>Starttijd</label>" +
                                    "<div class='col-sm-8 col-md-9'>" +
                                    "<input type='time' class='form-control' id='estarttime-" + response.events[i].match_id + "' name='starttime' value='" + response.events[i].starttime + "'>" +
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "</div>"+
                                    
                                    // Here is the button for editing the match
                                    "<div class='form-group btn-group'>"+
                                    "<button type='button' id='edit_match-" + response.events[i].match_id + "' class='btn btn-primary edit-match' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal-edit_match'>" +
                                    "Wijzigen" +
                                    "</button>" +
                                    "</div>"+
                                    "<hr/>"+
                                    "</form>"
                                );
                            }
                        } else {
                            display.innerHTML =  "Er zijn geen wedstrijden voor dit team.";
                        }
                    }
                });
            }).change();

            // Show info for confirmation in modal
            $('.edit-match').on("click", function() {
                var itemID = $(this).attr("id");
                var split = itemID.split("-");
                var id = split[1];
                var title = $("#etitle-"+id).val();
                var date = $("#edate-"+id).val();
                var starttime = $("#estarttime-"+id).val();

                var elem_id = document.getElementById("edit_match");
                var title_id = document.getElementById("modal-title-edit_match");
                var body_id = document.getElementById("modal-body-edit_match");

                var date = new Date(date + "T" + starttime);
                const date_options = { weekday: 'long', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'};
                const time_options = { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' };
                var datestring = date.toLocaleDateString('nl-NL', date_options);
                var timestring = date.toLocaleTimeString('nl-NL', time_options);

                title_id.innerHTML = "Wedstrijd wijzigen";
                body_id.innerHTML = "Titel: " + title +
                    "<br>Datum: " + datestring +
                    "<br>Starttijd: " + timestring +
                    "<br><br>Weet u zeker dat u deze wedstrijd wilt wijzigen?";
                $(".edit_match").attr("id", "edit_match-" + id);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The confirmation is not applied in the modal.

Below we have the modal. The modal is loaded. Only the javascript is not applied to the modal. It remains empty.

```
    <!-- BEGIN MODALS -->
    <!-- Modal after clicking on edit match -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-edit_match" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-title" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title-edit_match">Wedstrijd wijzigen</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Sluiten">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body-edit_match">

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Annuleren</button>
                    <button type="button" name="edit_match" id="edit_match" class="btn btn-primary edit_match">Wijzigen</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END MODALS -->
```

[image: An empty modal is shown when clicking on 'edit/wijzigen']

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try to break problem into small pieces. It's hard to debug when you paste and nothing works. If you want that someone quickliy debugs your code - make it runnable. Replace php calls with js array,  give them fake ids etc. For working with data I would provide something like separate file to get the single record (read about APIs) and connect to it with jQuery using data attribute taken from the list. Also split this into few files. Don't concatenate strings. Use php to prepare the view and return it from ajax, it will be cleaner.

Also we don't see what's inside your php files...

Comment: when you say it does not load when you try to do it in jquery 
have you tried checking the network tab(xhr) in the developer options in chrome.
does it hit the `show_overview.php` page at all?

Comment: Yes, that does work. It loads all the matches/events. It's the next piece that I don't get to work. 
// Show info for confirmation in modal  
$('.edit-match').on("click", function() {

Comment: i have done this type of things alot but i cant seem to actually understand your question 
:( 
however  instead of `$("#team-matchlist").change(function () {` try this 
`$(document).on('change','#team-matchlist', function (e) { `

Comment: That piece does work. That piece of code generates for each row a button edit. That button launch a modal called "modal-edit_match". The modal is opened (see image). The modal remains empty because the code "$('.edit-match').on("click", function() " doesn't change the inner html.

Comment: As cssBlaster21895 sugested. I went with breaking up the code. Making multiple pages for working data. Since then it is working perfectly.